# Why do I have to pass an argument on every method call?

Tags: python, python-class

I don't have to pass `self` but I have to pass `master` in line 4 of the the following code.

```
import game
window = game.Window()
cluster = game.Cluster(window)
cluster.circle(**window**,10,10,5)


. . .
class Cluster(Window):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.obj = []
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.hitbox = master.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,0,0)
    def update(self,master):
        master.canvas.coords(self.hitbox,min(self.x)-2,min(self.y)-2,max(self.x)+2,max(self.y)+2)
    def circle(self,master,x,y,r):
        self.obj += [master.canvas.create_oval(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r)]
        self.x += [x-r,x+r]
        self.y += [y-r,y+r]
        self.update(master)
```

Comment: The short answer is that you have to pass `master` into the functions because the functions use it. If you didn't want to always pass it in then you could store it in the `__init__` function for `Cluster`. If you wanted a more specific answer then you'll need to explain what other behaviour you would expect.

Comment: Assuming `master` is a widget that a given `Cluster` belongs to, you should probably just save it as another instance attribute and *not* require it to be passed to every method. Would it ever make sense to use *different* values for the same instance of `cluster`?

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to store the value of `master` as an instance attribute:

```
class Cluster(Window):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.obj = []
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.hitbox = master.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,0,0)
        self.master = master

    def update(self):
        self.master.canvas.coords(self.hitbox,min(self.x)-2,min(self.y)-2,max(self.x)+2,max(self.y)+2)

    def circle(self,x,y,r):
        self.obj += [self.master.canvas.create_oval(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r)]
        self.x += [x-r,x+r]
        self.y += [y-r,y+r]
        self.update()
```

So you don't have to pass it along to each method.

`self` gets a special treatment in Python and it's passed implicitly (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes):

> In C++ terminology, normally class members (including the data members) are public (except see below Private Variables), and all member functions are virtual. As in Modula-3, there are no shorthands for referencing the object’s members from its methods: the method function is declared with an explicit first argument representing the object, which is provided implicitly by the call. As in Smalltalk, classes themselves are objects. This provides semantics for importing and renaming. Unlike C++ and Modula-3, built-in types can be used as base classes for extension by the user. Also, like in C++, most built-in operators with special syntax (arithmetic operators, subscripting etc.) can be redefined for class instances.

Even more strictly speaking: the first argument - technically you can name it whatever you want (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks):

> Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that relies upon such a convention.